# Android 'leaking context' error

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context

I'm running an `AsyncTask` to retrieve some info via HTTP.

I'm calling this method from my main activity (`do_get_from_url()` is triggered by a button click):

```
private void do_get_from_url() {
    new getFromURL(this).execute();
}
```

The class that this calls is in the same `.java` file and starts as follows:

```
class getFromURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

  private MainActivity activity;

  getFromURL(MainActivity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
  }

  ...other code here...

  String linkURL = activity.link_url.getText().toString();

  String getFromURLrequestURL = activity.getString(R.string.short_url_request_url_base);

  ...other code here...

}
```

It seems that I need to use `activity` in order to access both the string resources and the UI element `link_url` from the main activity BUT the line `this.activity = activity` displays a warning in Android Studio that it is leaking a context.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773631/static-context-warning and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127346/android-studio-say-static-field-will-leak-contexts

Comment: I already thought it sounded like a leak to avoid, but that's pretty scary stuff... A bad error to leave in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause:** You are passing an activity as a context to a background thread. So the thread will keep a reference to the activity. As long as the thread running, the activity cannot be destroyed (by calling `finish()` method or users press back key to finish the activity). The term **leak** simply mean when an object or instance no longer used but the system cannot reclaim memory where they live on.
**Solution:** In Android you can use an API called `WeakReference`, Simply it will keep a **weak** reference to your object (in this case your activity), so when the activity get destroyed, it will not keep the reference anymore.

**getFromURL.java**

```
class getFromURL extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityWeakReference;

    getFromURL(MainActivity activity){
        mainActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }

  ...other code here...

    MainActivity activity = mainActivityWeakReference.get();
    // Always check this to make sure the activity haven't got destroyed yet.
    if (activity != null) {
        String linkURL = activity.link_url.getText().toString();
        String getFromURLrequestURL = activity.getString(R.string.short_url_request_url_base);
    }

  ...other code here...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Correct way is to use a WeakRefrence like this

```
WeakReference<MainActivity> parent;

GetFromURL(MainActivity activity){
   parent = new WeakReference(activity);
}

...other code here...

String linkURL = parent.get().link_url.getText().toString();

String getFromURLrequestURL = parent.get().getString(R.string.short_url_request_url_base);
```

...other code here...

Comment: The `patent = new WeakReference` line now gives an `Unchecked assignment` and an `Unchecked call` warning... Seems to work though...